# Question on the proof of Theorem 2.3.2 in Partial Differential Equations by Evans

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, heat-equation

I'm working through Evans's proof of the solution for the nonhomogenous heat equation (Theorem 2.3.2) and I'm getting stuck on a certain part.  He starts with the proposed solution: $$ u(x,t) = \int^t_0 \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dyds $$  In the middle of the proof, he calculates $$ u_t(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t) = \int^t_0 \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\Delta_x)f(x-y,t-s)dyds + \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,t)f(x-y,0)dy = \quad \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)(-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}-\Delta_y)f(x-y,t-s)dyds + \int^\varepsilon_0\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)(-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}-\Delta_y)f(x-y,t-s)dyds + \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,t)f(x-y,0)dy$$.  So far so good.  Evans then denotes $$I_\varepsilon = \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)(-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}-\Delta_y)f(x-y,t-s)dyds $$ and then argues that, by using integration by parts, we obtain:
$$ I_\varepsilon = \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}-\Delta_y)\Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dyds + \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,\varepsilon)f(x-y,t-\varepsilon)dy - \int_{Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,t)f(x-y,0)dy$$

This is where I am confused.  I tried working out the details of this integration by parts by first looking at the $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} $ part of the integral first.  Just looking at that part separately, we have $$ \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)[-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(x-y,t-s)]dyds =  \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\int^t_\varepsilon\Phi(y,s)[-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(x-y,t-s)]dsdy = \quad \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\int^t_\varepsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dsdy - \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} [\Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)]^t_\varepsilon dy = \int^t_\varepsilon\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dsdy - \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \Phi(y,t)f(x-y,0) dy + \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \Phi(y,\varepsilon)f(x-y,t-\varepsilon)dy$$

So that explains where the last two terms come from.  However, I'm confused about how to handle the Laplacian part of this integral.  Using Green's third identity, we have $$ \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\Phi(y,s)(-\Delta_y f(x-y,t-s))dyds = \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}-\Delta_y \Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dyds + \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\partial \Bbb{R}^n} [\Phi(y,s)\nabla f(x-y,t-s) \cdot \nu - f(x-y,t-s) \nabla \Phi(y,s) \cdot \nu]dS $$

Here, $\nu$ is the outward facing unit normal vector.  Based on the result that Evans gets, I assume that $$(\ast) \quad \int^t_\varepsilon \int_{\partial \Bbb{R}^n} [\Phi(y,s)\nabla f(x-y,t-s) \cdot \nu - f(x-y,t-s) \nabla \Phi(y,s) \cdot \nu]dS = 0 $$  but I'm not sure how to verify this.  I'm also not sure what it means to integrate a function over $\partial \Bbb{R}^n$ (I don't know what the boundary of $\Bbb{R}^n$ would be. So my question is, is my work thus far correct, and if so, how do I verify that ($\ast$) is correct?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f$ has compact support, as stated right before the Theorem,  so the integral is over some large ball (in space).

Comment: Thanks GReyes, that helps clarify it a lot.  Is the idea then that integrating over the boundary of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is simply taking the limit as $ r \to \infty$ of the integral over the ball $B(0,r)$?  If so, I can see how the compact support of f ensures that ($\ast$) holds.

Comment: That is right. Integrating over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the exactly the same as integrating over a ball containing the support of $f$. On the. boundary of such ball, both $f$ and all sort of derivatives are zero.